# I hid that camera icon and the Y,Z,X axis accidentally. How do I get it back?

Tags: interface

[image: The icons should be in the red rectangle were supposed to be.]
The icons should be in the red rectangle were supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

The name of you have hid is **Sidebar**.

There is three ways to unhide Sidebar:

1. 3d Viewport > Menu > View > Check Sidebar

   [image]
2. Click Arrow at the right corner of viewport

   [image]
3. Shortcut **N**

Answer (score 1):

You just disabled you *Gizmo* overlay.
Click the icon to enable it again.
Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + `</kbd>

[image]